# Stop Reviving Insider Builds (Cannot Find Button)

Tags: windows

Is there a way I can stop receiving insider builds on Windows 10? I just got build 14316 and would like to roll back to the latest generally available one. My only problem is that I can't find how. All the Google searches referred to a setting I don't seem to have. This is the settings page that is supposed to have an option to opt-out:

[image: Bad settings page]

Comment: I was able to find the option on my Windows 10 Insider VM but the image you supplied isn't even the correct location.

Comment: So where is the correct location?

Comment: I am to lazy to boot my VM remotely, but verified on the machine I am using that, Advanced Options should have it.  Can you verify which build you are using by providing a sanitized image of `winver'?  You really should wait until Windows 10 Version 1607 is released this July before you exit the Insider Preview program since your current built if its 14316 will eventually expire.  Are you using a local account or an account connected to a MS account and can you verify your NOT using the built-in Administrator account?

Comment: What do you mean about the 14316 build expiring? I have a fully licensed copy of Windows 10 Professional...

Comment: You do understand cannot stay on build 14316 forever right?  You eventually will be forced to upgrade to the Version 1607 build which will be released in July which is the reason I suggest you continue to receive updates then remove yourself from the program.  Waiting on those answers before I submit an answer.

Comment: No I did not :/. Why would MS release this?

Comment: Release what exactly? Insider Preview build have always expired.

Comment: Hehe ok, did not know that. How can I roll back to the most stable (public) version?

Comment: You should be able to download then mount the Windows 10 Version 1511 .ISO and install Windows 10 choosing to keep everything.